# jquery autocomplete bug? or wrong version?

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete, arrays

so let say i have an json object which i get from asmx file / web service file.

```
[
    {
        "UserName": "hl",
        "FirstName": "hendra",
        "LastName": "lim"
    },
    {
        "UserName": "wd",
        "FirstName": "wildan",
        "LastName": "dan"
    },
    {
        "UserName": "gd",
        "FirstName": "genin",
        "LastName": "gn"
    },
    {
        "UserName": "tr",
        "FirstName": "tere",
        "LastName": "magda"
    }
]
```

when i try to access it, i do this :

```
 $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            $("#tags").val(ui.item.FirstName);
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#tags").val(ui.item.FirstName);
            return false;
        }
});
```

you know what?? it is not working... this give me a headache for 2 days. but then i change my json object to this :

```
[{"label": "hendra", "value": "hl"}, 
 {"label":"wildan", "value": "wd"}, 
 { "label": "genin", "value": "gn"}, 
 {"label": "hendrik", "value":  "hdrik"}]

$("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
             focus: function (event, ui) {
            $("#tags").val(ui.item.label);
                   $('#key').val(ui.item.value);
            return false;
        },
         select: function (event,ui){
                    $('#tags').val(ui.item.label);
              $('#key').val(ui.item.value);
             return false;
                }
    });
```

and this is working, but now i am wondering why jquery autocomplete did not work when i use the first method, wasting my time for 2 days and give super headache to figure it out, but still can't get it, jquery did not working if i use

```
ui.item.FirstName
```

but it working with

```
ui.item.label or ui.item.value
```

is there something wrong with my first method? i think it is almost the same with the second one, the only different is in the json object, one is using "UserName, FirstName, etc"  and another one using "label, and value".

Answer (score 0):

Try this...... U have to use

> ```
> $.each(data, function(key, value) {
>      LocalityArray[key] = value.LocalityName;
> });
> ```

My example.

```
function GetLocalityList() {
    var LocalityArray = [];
    $.post("MvcLayer/Index/GetLocalityList",
    {
        CityID: $('#sltCity').val()
    },
    function(data) {
        // My sql query will be like this select LocalityID, CityID, LocalityName from tablename where CityID = 20
        // Here (data) is array format. Like this
        // [{"LocalityID":9397,"CityID":55,"LocalityName":"Adugodi"},{"LocalityID":9398,"CityID":55,"LocalityName":"Aga Abbas Ali Road"},{"LocalityID":9399,"CityID":55,"LocalityName":"Agaram"},{"LocalityID":9400,"CityID":55,"LocalityName":"Agrahara Dasara Halli"},{"LocalityID":9401,"CityID":55,"LocalityName":"Agrahara Dasarahalli"},{"LocalityID":9402,"CityID":55,"LocalityName":"Airport Exit Road"},{"LocalityID":9403,"CityID":55,"LocalityName":"Horamavu"},{"LocalityID":9404,"CityID":55,"LocalityName":"Hosakere Halli"},{"LocalityID":9405,"CityID":55,"LocalityName":"Hennur"},{"LocalityID":9406,"CityID":55,"LocalityName":"Hesaraghatta"},{"LocalityID":9407,"CityID":55,"LocalityName":"HKP Road"},{"LocalityID":9408,"CityID":55,"LocalityName":"HMT Layout"},{"LocalityID":9409,"CityID":55,"LocalityName":"Hongasandra"},{"LocalityID":9410,"CityID":55,"LocalityName":"Hoody"},{"LocalityID":9411,"CityID":55,"LocalityName":"Hayes Road"}    ]

        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            LocalityArray[key] = value.LocalityName;
        });
        $("#txtLocality").autocomplete({
            minLength: 1,
            source: LocalityArray
        });
    },
    'json'
    );
}
```

Comment: i might try it at monday, coz i left my source code at office, thx anyway. will let you know if it working, and vote you up as well.